# ASP .Net C# code to send mail to multiple users whose mail id should be hide within a groupname

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email

Need some help to write a C# code to send mail to multiple users but the email id of the users have to be hidden within a name.

For example, I want to send mail to email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com, email4@email.com and at the To address instead of showing all these email id's, I want to append all these 4 email id's to a groupname say "allemailgroup" and send the mail so that all 4 individual mail id's will be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possible solutions are:

- Include the addresses that you want to hide as BCc in the email
- Create an email group on your mail server (containing all the individual email addresses) and use that email group address in your C# code

Comment: Thank you so much... And I am sorry to ask u dat can u please say how to create  an email group on the mail server.I am a freasher.

Comment: To create an email group, you'll have to contact your mail server administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a set of strings delimited by, and through
an iteration mail them to blind users as you want.

```
           string[] allemails = TextBox1.Text.Split(";");
        foreach (string recipientemail in allemails)
        {
            mail.Bcc.Add(recipientemail);
            smtp.Send(mail);
            mail.To.Clear();
        }
```

Bye

Comment: Thanks for the ans.....Will you help me to do the same thing in To address. That is I want to send through To address.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting those emails in `BCC` part (Blind Carbon Copy). Mails in this part simply won't be shown as recipients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to append all the mails inside a groupname and send it via To address.that is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This obviously isn't a complete snippet, but it has all of the parts you should need to plug into your existing attempt.

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

then further down your code...

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.CC.Add("allemailgroup@yourdomain.com");

foreach (string recipient in recipients) // assuming recipients is a List<string>
{
    message.Bcc.Add(recipient);
}
```